# How to get R to skip a line rather than throwing an error (when try() and is.error() are not working)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, error-handling, officer

I'm trying to use `officer` to make a report. However, sometimes, the plots that I want to add don't have enough data, so rather than throwing an error, I just want R to leave a blank space where that plot would go.

However, I've tried using `try()` and an if statement, but neither work. For `try()`, officer just skips over any line that uses it, even if the plot exists.

I've tried the `is.error()` function from the `BBmisc` package, but, despite the plot printing an error when you try to load it, is.error("error_plot") gives FALSE. (As an aside, if anyone familiar with BBmisc/ggplot2 knows why this is, I'm curious.)

How can I get officer to skip over these errors (and just the errors)?

```
#Set up

library(officer)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(BBmisc)
#Read in blank deck
blank_deck <- read_pptx()

#Define location for objects
my_location_1 <- ph_location(left = .43, top = 2.18, height = 2.36, width = 4.17)
my_location_2 <- ph_location(left = 5.39, top = 2.18, height = 2.36, width = 4.17)

#Make a simple plot--this plot is good
good_plot <- try(ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_col())

#Make a simple plot--this plot intentionally is wrong
error_plot <- try(ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~Species2))
```

Here's solution 1, with try()

```
#Note: run the code from the set up section first

sample <- blank_deck %>%
  add_slide(layout = "Title Slide", master = "Office Theme") %>%
  ph_with(value = "My Title", ph_location_label(ph_label = "Title 1")) %>%
  add_slide(layout = "Blank", master = "Office Theme") %>%
  try(ph_with(value = good_plot, location = my_location_1)) %>% 
  try(ph_with(value = error_plot, location = my_location_2)) %>% 
  add_slide(layout = "Title Slide", master = "Office Theme") %>%
  ph_with(value = "End", ph_location_label(ph_label = "Title 1")) %>%
  base::print(
    target = '/home/define/your/pathway/mydeck.pptx')
```

And here's my attempt at using an if/then statement with is.error():

```
sample <- blank_deck %>%
  add_slide(layout = "Title Slide", master = "Office Theme") %>%
  ph_with(value = "My Title", ph_location_label(ph_label = "Title 1")) %>%
  add_slide(layout = "Blank", master = "Office Theme") %>%
  if_else(is.error("good_plot"), (ph_with(value = empty_content(), location = my_location_1)),
                   (ph_with(value = error_plot, location = my_location_2))) %>%
  if_else(is.error("error_plot"), (ph_with(value = empty_content(), location = my_location_2)),
                   (ph_with(value = error_plot, location = my_location_2))) %>% 
  add_slide(layout = "Title Slide", master = "Office Theme") %>%
  ph_with(value = "End", ph_location_label(ph_label = "Title 1")) %>%
  base::print(
    target = '/home/define/your/pathway/mydeck.pptx')
```

Comment: This doesn't answer this question exactly, but a workaround is to run this in an R Markdown file. Then, in that chunk, set error = TRUE. By doing this, R will persist past the error, without requiring try(), is.error(), etc.

Answer (score 0):

##### Problem

This problem (at least in attempt 1) is caused by the faulty use of pipes `%>%`. A pipe takes the output from the code on its left side, and provides it as the **first argument** for the **first function** on the right side. (Though a `.` placeholder can be used to specify another argument position of the first function).

This code:

```
read_pptx() %>%
  add_slide(layout = "Blank", master = "Office Theme") %>%
  ph_with(value = good_plot, location = my_location_1) %>% 
  base::print(target = 'mydeck.pptx')
```

Would do the same as:

```
foo <- read_pptx()
foo <- add_slide(foo, layout = "Blank", master = "Office Theme")
foo <- ph_with(foo, value = good_plot, location = my_location_1)
base::print(foo, target = 'mydeck.pptx')
```

But your first attempt (simplified):

```
read_pptx() %>%
  add_slide(layout = "Blank", master = "Office Theme") %>%
  try(ph_with(value = good_plot, location = my_location_1)) %>% 
  base::print(target = 'mydeck.pptx')
```

Does the same as:

```
foo <- read_pptx()
foo <- add_slide(foo, layout = "Blank", master = "Office Theme") 
foo <- try(foo, ph_with(value = good_plot, location = my_location_1))
base::print(foo, target = 'mydeck.pptx')
```

Note the problem in line 3: the output from `add_slide()` is passed as first argument to `try()`, not to `ph_with()`.

##### Solution

Only use pipes if you want to pass output to the first function:

```
blank_deck <- read_pptx()

sample <- blank_deck %>%
          add_slide(layout = "Title Slide", master = "Office Theme") %>%
          ph_with(value = "My Title", ph_location_label(ph_label = "Title 1")) %>%
          add_slide(layout = "Blank", master = "Office Theme")

try(sample <- ph_with(sample, value = good_plot, location = my_location_1))

try(sample <- ph_with(sample, value = error_plot, location = my_location_2))

sample <- sample %>% 
          add_slide(layout = "Title Slide", master = "Office Theme") %>%
          ph_with(value = "End", ph_location_label(ph_label = "Title 1")) %>%
          base::print(target = 'mydeck.pptx')
```

[image]